# SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error when inserting in database

Tags: android, sqlite

Good day, Just to make it short with relevant code,

If i do this in my activity:

```
     Intent i = getIntent();
          Bundle extras = i.getExtras();

          BitmapFactory.Options bf = new BitmapFactory.Options();
          bf.inSampleSize = 2;


          filename = extras.getString("pic_name");
          ImageView  iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
          Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, bf);
          iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
          setContentView(iv);

  registerForContextMenu(iv);



public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
       // weatherimagedb = new WeatherImageDB(this);
        //weatherimagedb.open();

        ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
        int selection = item.getItemId();
        switch(selection){
        case Holidays:

             vals.put(ImageDB.HOLIDAYS, filename);

        break;
        case Weather:
            vals.put(ImageDB.WEATHER, filename);

        break;
        }
             imagedb.tagImage(filename, vals); //logcat error is here

  return true;
}
```

And in the imageDB database class i have a method like this:

```
public long tagImage(String pathname, ContentValues val){  
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, val);    //logcat error is here

}
```

i get this error in database, but it does not crash my app:

```
05-19 02:44:55.580: E/Database(3088): Error inserting 
05-19 02:44:55.580: E/Database(3088): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO imagetags(null)  VALUES(NULL);
05-19 02:44:55.580: E/Database(3088):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
05-19 02:44:55.580: E/Database(3088):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
05-19 02:44:55.580: E/Database(3088):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
05-19 02:44:55.580: E/Database(3088):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
05-19 02:44:55.580: E/Database(3088):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
05-19 02:44:55.580: E/Database(3088):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1231)
05-19 02:44:55.580: E/Database(3088):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1658)
05-19 02:44:55.580: E/Database(3088):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1515)
05-19 02:44:55.580: E/Database(3088):   at com.MyApps.ImageUpdate.ImageDB.tagImage(ImageDB.java:82)
05-19 02:44:55.580: E/Database(3088):   at com.MyApps.ImageUpdate.ViewImage.onContextItemSelected(ViewImage.java:134)
05-19 02:44:55.580: E/Database(3088):   at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2254)
```

what could i be doing wrong please?.. am i not using the ContentValues correctly enough?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that your `selection` is neither `Holidays` nor `Weather`?

Comment: no i doubt its that. there are more options on the context Menu and i get the same error for all of them. am beginning to think some how the Content Values get Lost. but i don't know :(

Comment: @Sparrow: I'm pretty sure your `ContentValues` is empty... Why are you using integral constants instead of `R.id.x` values?

Comment: as you can see, its in a contextMenu and those values(ImageDB.HOLIDAYS and ImageDB.WEATHER) refer to columns in the database which i am trying to put the images in. I don't know whether i should change the tagImage method to take 2 String parameters and then initialize/use the Content Values within the method there?

Comment: @sparrow: I was talking about the `case`s of the `switch`. Are you manually creating a menu and setting each menu item to the constant `Holidays`, `Weather`, etc? Seems like a really bad choice.

Comment: Hmmm.. now i remember i was creating it manually before and then i switched to inflating it from an xml menu resource but the cases still refer to Menu.First, Menu.First + 1, Menu.First + 2, because i still wrote them in the same order when i did them manually etc.. hmmm.. could that be the reason? because in the xml menu resource, i am giving it a proper "id".

Comment: @sparrow: resource ids don't have _orders_, they are unique integers among the entire project constrained to a special range. Use `R.id.x` values instead of positions. Your `switch` is not entering into any of the `case`s.

Comment: so sorry for all the troubles. Feel very silly! if you did not mention that, would not have realise on time that the ids had changed. its working now. Thank you and Have a nice weekend. :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe none of the case switches is true in certain case, therefore nothing going to be added in "val".

Comment: @Hamsi, but am i not calling the method before it returns.